# Why is 人口 in this sentence 多, not 大?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, phrase, adjectives

> 中国是世界上人口最多的国家.

Why is 人口 in this sentence 多, not 大? In English way of thinking (or my English way of thinking), a population is something that can be "huge" rather than "much"/ "many". Is Chinese way of thinking different? Is 人口 really as shape of the characters says - "mouths of people" rather than "population" in the English sense? People are many, but population is huge. Can I say "中国是世界上人口最*大*的国家"?

I've got one more question about this structure. Countries and cities can be big in two senses: in population or in territory. This sentence says "China is the biggest country in the world, in the sense of population". I guess I could change the category into the other one and say: 俄罗斯是世界上国土最大的国家. I put 大 here. Is it correct? Would 多 be correct?

Comment: "中国是世界上人口最大的国家" As a joke, this sounds like "China has the biggest number of people in the World with big mouths" :)

Comment: 中国是世界上人口最大的国家: China is the country whose people has largest mouth in the world. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. I never think that 人口多(少) should be said as 人口大(小) in English way. As you said, 人口 seems meaning *people* more in Chinese sense. So we should say 人口多/人口少.

> Can I say "中国是世界上人口最大的国家"?

No, it's quite weird.

> 俄罗斯是世界上国土最大的国家. I put 大 here. Is it correct? Would 多 be correct?

Yes, 大 is correct, 多 is not. 国土 usually refer to the *area*, i.e. the antional territory area, then we should say 大(小), not 多(少).

As a supplementary, 规模 (scope/scale) could be described with 大/小, so you can say "中国是世界上人口规模最大的国家".

Another supplementary, 人口 belongs to a kind of usage that combines a noun and quantifier to make a 集合名词 (collective noun). E.g. 车辆, 人口, 纸张, 船只, 布匹, 马匹.

Comment: The second supplementary blew my mind, I've never noticed it!

Comment: @musialmi I didn't realize it either untill I did some search about 人口 just now. I'm just using it in daily life *naturally* without thinking too much especially about the grammar, construction, etc.

Comment: 人口 is 人口数量

I found these sentences as an example of 人口数量最大的  

当前埃及人口数量最大的不是小孩，而是15到25岁之间的群体，他们比较有上进心，消费欲望强，尤其是对于奢侈品以及新建家庭所需的东西消费力最强。 

作为世界上人口数量最大的国家，汉语拥有着世界上最多的使用者； Are they wrong??

Comment: @Pedroski Yes they are fine, even using 多 sounds more natural to me, i.e. 作为世界上人口数量最多的国家...

Answer (score 3):

Yes Chinese see "人口" as "number of **people**"  and 人口 is measured in number, e.g. China's population is 14 billion.  And 多 and (小) are appropriate adjective for 人口

English use big or small to describe population, because they are measuring '**number** of people' and 'number' is measured in size. 14 billion is a big number, the biggest number (of people in a country) in the world in fact.

国土 is 'area of a country' , and it is described by size, so 俄罗斯是世界上国土最大的国家 is correct

Answer (score 1):

口 may be used as measure word of 人. For example, you may heard 我家有五口人。 (There are 5 people in my family.)

口 may also used as the same meaning of 人. For example, 我们一家三口去武大看樱花<sup>[*](https://m.chinanews.com/wap/detail/zw/sh/2020/03-04/9113948.shtml)</sup> (My whole family, 3 people, (will) go to Wuhan University to see cherry blossom.)

Back to the question about 人口. Here is another example: 2000年，全世界有61亿人口。<sup>[*](https://www.un.org/development/desa/zh/news/population/world-population-prospects-2019.html)</sup> (By 2000, there are 6.1B people in the world) We can see that 人口 may be translated into *people* here but not *population*.

As you would say "more people" / "less people", but not "huge people". You should use 人口最多 / 人口最少 in that context.